# Laravel Passport return 401 with Select2 ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jquery-select2, laravel-spark, laravel-passport

I am using the Select2 plugin v 3.5.1 and I am trying to load remotely with ajax the options, but I get 401 from Laravel Passport.

When I make other requests with jQuery ajax the result is the same, but when I use VueJS the request succeeds.

Any ideas, why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure the authorization token is sent with the request headers? `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't set the csrf token ..
This code fixed the issue:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   headers: {
     'X-CSRF-Token': window.Spark.csrfToken
   }
});
```